# Is there a LyX way to add multiple cross-references to a document?

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I am using refstyle and can successfully call `\chapref{label-1,label-2}` in an ERT, which produces the desired "Chapters 3 and 4", but I was wondering if there was a way to do this via the GUI which would keep all the labels in sync across the documents if I were to update them. Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of a way. If you do not find a solution, could you please post an enhancement request at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?